# Discovering the shortest "path" between two people on Facebook

Tags: facebook, programming-languages

I am not a very experienced programmer with these kind of things, but I wanted to write a program that receives two Facebook profiles, and returns the shortest "path" of people between them.

I guess that the running time is huge and etc, but if I would start making that program, what language should I choose? What libraries should I use? What general direction should I go in?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to the language, you should use whatever you are most comfortable with. They have sample code for PHP, for example, so if you know PHP you could start with that. Java would work too.

Now, I don't know if the fbook API already has some function which performs this task. But, as you have already alluded to, you want to find the "shortest path." In fact, there are many algorithms out there which will find the shortest path between two nodes of a graph.

You are looking for the shortest path between two nodes of a graph. What's a graph?

A graph just what it sounds like - a collection of nodes and edges. In this case, each person would be a node. And the edges, which connect nodes, are formed by friendships.

So lets say you have *Friend X*, who has friends {A, B, C, D} and *Friend Y*, who has friends (B, D, E, F}. You's start by creating a graph of all of the friends (that is, take the *union* of the two sets). {A, B, C, D, E, F, X, Y} We include X and Y because we ultimately want to find the shortest distance between those two.

Once you get the social graph of each friend (who are their friends, are they friends with each other, etc) then you can place them into a graph structure. I won't talk about how to do that - just going big-picture here.

One way to represent that is with an adjacency matrix:

```
  A B C D E F X Y
A 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
B      ...
C
D
E
F
X
Y
```

That is, look at each grid item. If the two people are friends, put a "1" in their cross-section, otherwise a "0".

Now apply a shortest-path algorithm to that data. You could use Dijkstra's Algorithm to accomplish this.

So: you need to have a little background on graphs, adjacency matrices, and shortest path algorithms. There might even be a Java library that does all this for you. Or even a PHP or R library. But at a high level, this is what you are trying to accomplish. I'm not even sure if the fbook API will give you all the data you need to solve this.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the very in-depth answer, and it clearly made me think about what algorithm I should use (I wanted to just run the BFS algorithm from one of the people in question until we find the second one), but my question was more about the technical part.

How do I parse the information? How do I get to the friends list from the main page and gt the link to their profile? etc.

Comment: @GBoss haha, okay, sorry about that, I wasn't sure whether you were asking about the "algorithm" or the "fbook api" part. BFS is fine, but that won't gaurantee a *shortest* path (and there might be multiple shortest paths, so you will get *a* shortest path.) I am not very good at the fbook API, though, so I'm afraid I don't have much help there. I'll be interested to see what you find out.

Comment: Since the distances are uniform here, Dijkstra's algorithm just reduces to BFS anyway. A slight improvement would be to do a BFS from both people and meet in the middle.

Comment: Facebook has a Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api). I am not sure whether Facebook Graph means what we mean by Graph in DSA.

Answer (score 0):

> What language should I choose?

Any language your are comfortable to use.

> What libraries should I use? What general direction should I go in?

Try: BFS (queue) and DFS(Stack or recursive).